# Can't serve a site with fabric, but fabric is installed

Tags: python, fabric

I'm [writing some code for a project that requires](https://github.com/NUKnightLab/juxtapose/blob/master/DEVELOPER.md) virtualenvwrapper and I can't get my development up and running, I believe because of a problem with Fabric. I'm on OS X Yosemeti with Python 2.7.2 (32 bit) and I believe have followed the developer documentation for the project correctly.

In my virtualenv environment I have all the requirements satisfied:

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Flask==0.10.1 in /Users/benjamin/.virtualenvs/juxtapose/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Jinja2==2.7 in /Users/benjamin/.virtualenvs/juxtapose/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): MarkupSafe==0.18 in /Users/benjamin/.virtualenvs/juxtapose/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Werkzeug==0.9.3 in /Users/benjamin/.virtualenvs/juxtapose/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): boto==2.27.0 in /Users/benjamin/.virtualenvs/juxtapose/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 5))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): itsdangerous==0.22 in /Users/benjamin/.virtualenvs/juxtapose/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 6))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): paramiko==1.10.1 in /Users/benjamin/.virtualenvs/juxtapose/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 7))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): ply==3.4 in /Users/benjamin/.virtualenvs/juxtapose/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 8))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pycrypto==2.6 in /Users/benjamin/.virtualenvs/juxtapose/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 9))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): wsgiref==0.1.2 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.1/lib/python2.7 (from -r requirements.txt (line 10))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): gunicorn==19.3.0 in /Users/benjamin/.virtualenvs/juxtapose/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 11))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Fabric==1.6.1 in /Users/benjamin/.virtualenvs/juxtapose/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Fabric-1.6.1-py2.7.egg (from -r requirements.txt (line 12))
Cleaning up...
```

However when I run `fab serve` I get the error

```
(juxtapose)benjamin:juxtapose benjamin$ fab serve

Warning: Command(s) not found:
serve
```

I was expecting to be sent to a site e.g. localhost:4000 when I ran `fab serve`. Do you know why I could be getting this error and how I can fix it?

Thanks

Comment: It looks like it depends on this repo: https://github.com/NUKnightLab/fablib Have you installed that according to the instructions also?

Comment: Hello David. I downloaded fablib to alongside my juxtapose directory (although I am not using AWS and I don't have the access rights to clone github.com:NUKnightLab/secrets.git). `fab serve` still doesn't work. Do I need to have AWS for fablib to be installed or am I missing something obvious?